# Images invisible on catalog page upon resizing images in view.xml

Tags: xml, image, category-page

I have changed the size of image in ***view.xml*** as

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">


    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>165</width>
                <height>186</height>
            </image>
            <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
                <width>165</width>
                <height>186</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
```

in my mobile theme.

After this, I flushed the cache and upgraded it but the resulted as

[image: the resulted output]

Comment: You are run images resize command??

Comment: I did it but doesn't work